# perl coro segmentation fault

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault

I have a Perl code using [coro](https://metacpan.org/pod/Coro) version 6.06.

This is my code:

```
{
package AAA;
use AnyEvent::HTTP::LWP::UserAgent;
use Coro;
use Coro::AnyEvent; BEGIN { *CORE::GLOBAL::sleep = \&Coro::AnyEvent::sleep; };

sub new { return bless {} => shift };

sub main {
    my ($self) = @_;

    my $count = 1000;
    my $h = {};
    while (1) {
        while (keys %$h >= $count ) {
            sleep 1;
        }

        my $task = rand(1000);

        my $coro = async (
            sub {
                my ($self, $task) = @_;
                sleep( rand(1000) );
                print ": $self - $coro - $task\n";
            } => ($self, $task)
        );

        $h->{$coro} = $coro;
        $coro->on_destroy(sub {
            delete $h->{$coro};
            undef $coro;
        });
    }
    }
 }

AAA->new->main;
```

From time to time (like 1 time in a day) it fails with segmentation fault error.

What bug can it be and how can i detect it?

Answer (score 0):

Without a backtrace (e.g. from a coredump) it's hard to say why, because you gave no information on where it crashes.

However, crashes with C libraries (e.g. EV or Coro) are common because of a longstanding bug in perl: When the interpreter exits, it sometimes corrupts data structures (usually ones that are directly or indirectly part of a circular data structure), that is, perl might free structures that are still referenced elsewhere.

Creating circular data structures is somewhat easier with callback-heavy code such as code using AnyEvent or Coro.

The following scenario could cause this: Your program exits (for example, because it throws an exception without catching it, e.g. due to a runtime error) and during program exit, perl than corrupts some C data structure causing the segfault, which also means you don't actually get to see the error message.

In a backtrace from a coredump you might be able to see a call to Perl_croak or Perl_vcroak with the actual error.

The only workaround for that perl bug is to free data structures yourself on program exit (by e.g. undef'ing global variables yourself before exiting). If you can't do that (e.g. because you have no clue with one it is :), you can catch runtime errors yourself (by wrapping your code into eval) and instead of exiting the program normally, you can print the error and call POSIX::_exit 1 for example.

Using AnyEvent::Debug will wrap all watcher callbacks into an eval and report errors for them, so that might be a start.